# curl command not working on M1 bash command line

Tags: bash, kubernetes, apple-m1

currently busy learning kubernetes and running configs on the command line, and I'm using an M1 MacOS running on version 11.5.1, and one of the commands I wanted to run is `curl "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME/proxy"` but I get the below error message `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`. Not sure if anyone has experienced this issue before, would appreciate the help.

Comment: What's the value of $POD_NAME? You can run `echo "|$POD_NAME|"` to find out. I've added pipes on both ends to see any trailing spaces etc.

Comment: I get the following since I've two pods running `|kubernetes-bootcamp-57978f5f5d-fg68p
kubernetes-dockerdemo-844f68dd86-jvqzh|`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. `curl` request should be done to a single pod, not 2+. Same as its name should be without any special characters. Just made a curl request on my macOS with the `export POD_NAME=blabla` and the same command you have. It works. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `curl` command should receive only 1 host, not multiple hosts.
Therefore pod should be single.

Then, you need to save POD's name to a variable without any special characters.

Last, when you're using `kubectl proxy`, you need to add `-L` option to the `curl` command so it will follow the redirection.

Simple example will be:

```
# run pod with echo image
kubectl run echo --image=mendhak/http-https-echo

# start proxy
kubectl proxy

# export pod's name
export POD_NAME=echo

# curl with `-I` - headers and `-L` - follow redirects
curl -IL http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME/proxy
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/echo/proxy/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: this is super helpful, managed to get it working now, even though you omitted the -I, but I managed to run it as follows `curl -IL http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/kubernetes-bootcamp-57978f5f5d-fg68p/proxy` based on this simple example and voila it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that POD_NAME contains two pods separated by space. Therefore the url that you are trying to refer is

1. malformed - because of space in it - and that's the reason for the error message
2. wrong - you need to put name of the pod you want to access in there, not both at once

Comment: Ok cool, so  I did exactly what you guided me on, however after parsing the pod name on the curl command without the $ I get nothing, but after adding the $ in front of the pod name, I get the following error `{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "pods \"-bootcamp-57978f5f5d-fg68p\" not found",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    "name": "-bootcamp-57978f5f5d-fg68p",
    "kind": "pods"
  },
  "code": 404
}%       `

Comment: I haven't really worked with kubernetes, but my  guess is that URL must be `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/kubernetes-bootcamp-57978f5f5d-fg68p/proxy`. Is that the value you are using? The error message looks like the pod name you are trying to access is wrong.

Comment: I definitely used that url, but that's the one that returns nothing, and then when I include $ I get the error message attached above. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @msingathimajola Add -L to the curl command which gives you nothing so it will follow the redirection.

Comment: $ is definitely wrong. But that's all I know.

Comment: thanks @YaroslavFyodorov. I added the -L @moonkotte and I got the below `{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "error trying to reach service: dial tcp 10.1.0.6:80: connect: connection refused",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}%   ` FYI I'm trying to test my pod running a curl command.

Comment: @msingathimajola `503` means that application/service inside your pod is not working correctly.